# Why can't I install my SSD into this 2.5" enclosure "Optimized for SSD"?

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive

I want to use this Union Memory SSD as an external backup, and connect it by USB to my laptop.

[image]

I want to reuse my empty [2.5'' External Hard Drive Enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LY97QE8) that advertises SSD below. But why can't I slot my SSD in it? Did Orico falsely advertise their enclosure as compatible with SSD?

Must I buy [an enclosure designed solely for SSD's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08R58MNCZ)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: SSDs come with SATA, mSATA, M.2, U.2, SAS …. Much like HDDs (used to) come with IDE, SATA, SCSI, SAS, ….

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image clearly states: Support all 2,5 inch [etc.] You don't have a 2.5 inch SSD, you have an M.2 SSD.

There are M.2 to 2.5 inch converters available, but they tend to be more expensive than a new enclosure, so you're better off buying an M.2 enclosure, such as the one you mentioned, or this one https://www.act-connectivity.com/en-us/usb-c-m-2-sata-and-nvme-ssd-enclosure-ac1605